# Testing Push Notifications in Laravel Dusk

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

So I have an app that can bring up push notifications in the browser. The problem is that I need to create a UI test using Laravel Dusk to test if the push notification actually appears in the user's browser.

In real applications, push notifications are triggered from the server side in real-time using Websocket. Because there is some code logic in the front end before popping the push notification, so I think using [Mocking Event Fake](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#event-fake) is still not enough.

I have tried reading the official documentation on [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk) but unfortunately haven't found a solution.

With an example page like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Show Notification</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/push.js/1.0.8/push.min.js" integrity="sha512-eiqtDDb4GUVCSqOSOTz/s/eiU4B31GrdSb17aPAA4Lv/Cjc8o+hnDvuNkgXhSI5yHuDvYkuojMaQmrB5JB31XQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector('button')

        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            Push.create('Hello world!', {
                body: 'Foo',
                icon: 'https://example.com/images/icon.png',
                link: 'https://example.com/',
                timeout: 4000,
                onClick: function () {
                    window.focus();
                    this.close();
                },
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution I might expect is something like this:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function itShouldBeAbleToShowPushNotifications(): void
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser): void {
            $browser
                ->visit('/')
                ->allowPushNotification() // The actual method doesn't exist, it's just an example I was hoping for
                ->click('button')
                ->assertSeePushNotification( // The actual method also doesn't exist
                    title: 'Hello world',
                    body: 'Foo',
                    icon: 'https://example.com/images/icon.png',
                    link: 'https://example.com/'
                );
        });
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or maybe there is a better alternative?